# Send daily email with results of report

Tags: email, reporting

I have a pre-existing report that I want to be automatically ran once a day, then sent to certain email addresses. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Refer this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_schedule.htm&type=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the report, then click the Run Report dropdown, and choose Schedule Future Runs. You can choose the frequency and recipients. You can read more in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_schedule.htm&type=0).